# Is it possible to set QApplication style in QtDesigner?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am currently working on a GUI application using PyQt5 and QtDesigner. As I have to make it multi-platform (at least Ubuntu and W10) I will use the "Fusion" style to make it look similar on both platforms.

I was wondering if one could simply set the QApplication style directly in QtDesigner ? I know that a simple <<.setStyle("Fusion")>> will do the trick in the code, but does it exist within QtDesigner so the lines can be automatically generated ?

I'm trying to learn QtDesigner and how much it can be pushed before going into the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to set the style through Qt Designer.

What Qt Designer does allow is to display the GUI with different styles if you select Form-> Preview -> ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, this is in QtCreator 11.0.3:

[image]

This option also exists in core Designer as seen in this [forum post](https://forum.freecad.org/viewtopic.php?t=39749)